# Does Powershell have an automatic log, or do I have to write log functions to my scrips?

Tags: powershell

I have mainly been writing syntax for statistics software such as SPSS, STATA and SAS, and I am fairly new to coding in PowerShell. I am used to beeing able to scan a log file for finding out what my script does, for example what values are assigned to a variable or which iteration of a loop is running.

But when I run my PowerShell script (using PowerShell ISE), I dont get any message at all unless there is a fatal error in the script. I get no errors, but the script doesn't execute the rigth action, so I know there is an error somewhere. When I  write the code sentence by sentence to the console, I get outputs telling me what goes on, but once I run the enitre script, there is no output to keep track on. Is there a way to view a log from the script, or do I have to implicitly write log functions into the script? From my googling, this seems to be the case, but I would hate to spend hours writing log-code just to find that I could have just openede x folder and find what I was looking for

Comment: You probably already know, but just in case you don't, you can single step through your code in the ISE, and you can set breakpoints in your code. You can examine the contents of variables (mouse-over them or evaluate them in the console) when single-stepping.

Answer (score 4):

in addition to @Vesper's reply, you can use [start-transcript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) cmdlet to record each command and response to a logfile.
ie

`start-transcript -path c:\logs\logfile.txt`

and 
[set-psdebug](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd315302.aspx) could be a great help too

Answer (score 1):

`start-transcript` is mainly based on recording screen output (`Write-Host`) which is often questionable where it concerns variables with unexpected contents. Besides, there are no time stamps and other features you might expect from script logging.
Therefore I have written my own [`Log-Entry` framework](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Debug` or `Write-Warning` to produce logs, and then set respective preference variable to "continue" and run script with added parameter `3>file.log` where the number is 3 for warnings, 4 for verbose and 5 for debug messages. This applies to Powershell 3.0 and above.

For Powershell 2.0, you can do `Write-Default` as log dumper and forward the script output into a file.

If neither satisfies you, you can open a log file in your script and forward any strings you want to log by piping to `Out-file $logfile -append`.